# crystal reports multiple function in formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I am looking to execute 2 Replace functions on the same report field.

When I try

```
Replace({letter_master.letterBody},'{provider}',{provider.provider_name});
Replace({letter_master.letterBody},'{TotalBalance}',ToText(ToNumber({visit_master.value_7})))
```

as the formula for the letterBody field, only the second replace is returned.

How can I execute BOTH replace statements on the letterBody field to get both placeholders replaced with real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try..

```
Replace(
Replace({letter_master.letterBody},'{provider}',provider.provider_name})
,'{TotalBalance}',ToText(ToNumber({visit_master.value_7})))
```